# Why am I getting 'ValueError: Error when checking input: ...' only when I load my keras model but not when I first fit it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have trained a number of character level language models using keras. When I first fit a model I can use it, but when I save the model then try to use it later I get a Value Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (3, 54) but got array with shape (3, 52)
```

Why am I getting this error only when I load the model, and how can I use the models I have saved?

I've tried to find solutions to the issue online but most google results seem to be about the dimensions changing. All that's changing in my case is that the saved models seem to expect one hot vectors which are two longer than they should be.

For clarity sake, there are 52 characters, so (3, 52) should be correct.

Here is the code I'm using to build the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(40, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=2)
```

Here is how I'm saving it:

```
model.save('n3_Tokeniser.h5')
```

Here's how I load it:

```
model = load_model('n3_Tokeniser.h5')
```

Here's how I try to call it:

```
def generate_seq(model, mapping, seq_length, seed_text, n_chars):
    in_text = seed_text
    for _ in range(n_chars):
        encoded = [mapping[char] for char in in_text]
        encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen=seq_length, truncating='pre')
        encoded = to_categorical(encoded, num_classes=len(mapping))
        yhat = model.predict_classes(encoded, verbose=0)
        out_char = ''
        for char, index in mapping.items():
            if index == yhat:
                out_char = char
                break
        in_text += char
    return in_text
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ade/PycharmProjects/Wbp/LSTM.py", line 263, in <module>
    print(generate_seq(model, chardict, pre_characters, '$$$$$$$$$$', 20))
  File "/Users/ade/PycharmProjects/Wbp/LSTM.py", line 250, in generate_seq
    yhat = model.predict_classes(encoded, verbose=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 267, in predict_classes
    proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (3, 54) but got array with shape (3, 52)
```

Comment: Please print the x_train shapes. Are they same when saving the model and when loading the model back? Probably there is a discrepancy.

Comment: Do your `x_train` and `encoded` have the same shape? Since it expects shape `(3, 54)`, maybe your `x_train` shape is wrong.

Comment: `x_train`'s final shape before the model is built is (1463914, 3, 52)